# Database structure for combaning local login with social login

Tags: google, login, facebook, social-networks

I'm implementing a platform where users can create an account with my system and use it to login. Also I allow them to add any external login (social login) such as Facebook, Google, Twitter and so on. The mechanics is similar to what Stack Overflow offers (Edit Profile & Settings > My Logins).

This is what I came up with:

[image: Social Login]

Is there any other better approach to this problem?

Comment: What is your biggest concern? i.e. What would another approach have to accomplish to make it better? Performance, ease of adding another service, adhering to the rules of Normalization, show everyone how sophisticated of a programmer you are? Nothing is going to achieve all of these. Some platforms already have proven frameworks for security.

Comment: lol. I'm after speed.